# Is there a way to set multiple parameters with one choice in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to manage a jenkins build where a user may select to build either from master, or a specific branch.  There are several variables that need to be set depending on what the user chooses.  I've spent all day trying to find any reasonable way of doing this, and the best thing I've come up with is offering the user two dropdowns populated with low level parameter values.

Comment: What is the solution you are using now? TiA Christian

Comment: A variation of choice and string parameters.  A user editable choice (refs/heads or refs/tags).  A user editable string (branch or tag name), and two string parameters, one for the refspec and one for the branch.  Those are built using the first two parameters and built in variables.  There is no validation :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set up two jobs by using different branch, that will be better, since different branch might will has different datamodel, setup a different schema for each of them will make more sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many projects and branches to do that.

Comment: hmmm, but do you guys have datamodel as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [environment script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) and execute a shell script to define and populate your build variables.

Comment: This is specifically about building the UI in jenkins.  The variables that I am trying to populate relate to SCM, so are outside the scope of building.  I was hoping there would be a simple feature or plug-in somewhere.

Comment: From your description https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin seem to be the one you need but I haven't used it so I can't really tell. You can check the full list here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Extensible Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin). The global choice parameter might be exactly what you want.

Comment: I looked at this, but tags are not global parameters.  I'll take another look though.

Comment: you can put a variable into the checkout URL.

Answer (score 0):

You make a single choice parameter and than add "Inject environment variables" step specifying `MyBuildConfig\${ChosenParameter}.prop` in Properties File Path. Create such a file for each of the choice options. Finally, specify additional variables you want to set together with particular chosen parameter in each of the created files.